# How to assign file name with full path to a variable in bash script

Tags: command-line

Suppose I opened my file manager `nemo` and select a file named "abc"
In the location bar, it shows media/myuser/folder1/subfoler/ and the selected file name is abc.

How can assign the selected (highlighted) file name with full path in a variable in my bash script (please note this file is not in home directory) 
anybody can help me please?

Comment: You need to be a bit more specific about what exactly you're trying to achieve...

Answer (score 0):

You can put commands like these in your script:

```bash
#! /bin/bash

path=/anyfolder/anyfolder/anyfolder
cd "$path"
```

Comment: The OP is using a graphical file manager and is asking how to include and use the path of the selected file not the directory in bash. Your answer ( while you clearly know how to do it ) needs more expanding to specifically address the OP's issue and help solve it. Also `PATH` in uppercase will overwrite the existing executable path variable. So, use lowercase instead. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In Nemo (or Nautilus), use *Right Click -> Copy* or simply press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

Then, in the terminal you can use `xclip` to get the full path:

```
file="$(xclip -o -selection clipboard)"
filename="${file##*/}"
```

If you need a better solution, you can use Nautilus/Nemo "Actions".